# Ошибки при запуске. ExceptioException in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerExceptionn

Tags: java, gui

При запуске программы возникает куча ошибок, не могу понять по какой причине. В коде ошибок не вижу, отладчиком тоже несколько раз проходился, ничего не меняется. Возможно, что-то очевидное, но я сам, к сожалению, не вижу и понять что же не так не могу, т.к. новичок в этом деле. Буду крайне благодарен за вашу помощь. Единственное, что могу добавить это то, что ошибки пропадают, когда удаляю строку this.b = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText()); , но она мне нужна для дальнейшего использования в программе, поэтому просто удалить не могу, хочу найти конкретную ошибку.  [image]

```
package javaapplication41;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public NewJFrame() {
        this.b = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
        initComponents();
    }

                            
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel11 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField5 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel12 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField6 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField7 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel13 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField8 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField9 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField13 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField15 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel14 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel15 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField11 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField17 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel16 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenuItem2 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenuItem3 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 204));

        jLabel2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/javaapplication41/newpackage/tumblr_static_sleepy_cat.gif"))); // NOI18N

        jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jButton2.setText("Сохранить");
        jButton2.setFocusPainted(false);
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Я просыпаюсь с ");

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("единицами энергии.");

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setText("Я трачу на ");

        jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setText("подъем с кровати");

        jTextField2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jTextField2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel6.setText("единиц энергии.");

        jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel7.setText("завтрак");

        jTextField3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jTextField3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel8.setText("единиц энергии.");

        jLabel9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel9.setText("утренние проц-ры");

        jTextField4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jTextField4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel10.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel10.setText("единиц энергии.");

        jLabel11.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel11.setText("дорогу");

        jTextField5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jTextField5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel12.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel12.setText("единиц энергии.");

        jTextField6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jTextField6.setText("впиши что-то свое");

        jTextField7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jTextField7.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField7ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel13.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel13.setText("единиц энергии.");

        jTextField8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jTextField8.setText("впиши что-то свое");

        jTextField9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jTextField9.setText("впиши что-то свое");

        jTextField13.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jTextField13.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField13ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField15.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jTextField15.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField15ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel14.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel14.setText("единиц энергии.");

        jLabel15.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel15.setText("единиц энергии.");

        jTextField11.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jTextField11.setText("впиши что-то свое");

        jTextField17.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jTextField17.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField17ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel16.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel16.setText("единиц энергии.");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 134, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 51, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(jLabel3))
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel7)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel9)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel11)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField11, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 51, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel6))
                                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 51, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel8))
                                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 51, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel10))
                                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 51, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel12))
                                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(jTextField13, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 51, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel14))
                                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(jTextField15, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 51, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel15))
                                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(jTextField7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 51, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel13))
                                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(jTextField17, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 51, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel16)))))
                        .addGap(0, 106, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel6))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel8)
                    .addComponent(jLabel9))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel10)
                    .addComponent(jLabel7))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel11)
                    .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel12))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 21, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel13))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 21, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField13, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel14))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 21, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField15, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel15))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField11, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 21, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField17, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel16))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 39, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        jMenuBar1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jMenuBar1.setBorder(null);
        jMenuBar1.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        jMenuBar1.setSelectionModel(null);

        jMenu1.setText(" Файл");

        jMenuItem1.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_S, java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
        jMenuItem1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jMenuItem1.setText("Сохранить");
        jMenuItem1.setBorder(null);
        jMenu1.add(jMenuItem1);

        jMenuItem2.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_DELETE, java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
        jMenuItem2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jMenuItem2.setText("Очистить");
        jMenuItem2.setBorder(null);
        jMenu1.add(jMenuItem2);

        jMenuItem3.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0));
        jMenuItem3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jMenuItem3.setText("Закрыть");
        jMenuItem3.setBorder(null);
        jMenuItem3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jMenuItem3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenu1.add(jMenuItem3);

        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

        jMenu2.setText("Справка");
        jMenu2.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jMenu2MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenu2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jMenu2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }                                           

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        
        try {
            FileWriter FR1 = new FileWriter(jTextField1.getText(),false);
            FR1.write("У тебя" + " " + jTextField1.getText() + " " + "единиц энергии при пробуждении");
            FR1.flush();
            FR1.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Не удалось сохранить ваш текст");
        }
        lastfile = jTextField1.getText();
        jTextField1.setText(""); 
    }                                        
    
    int a,b;
    String lastfile;
   
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        
        try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Metal".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication41.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    }
                    
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel11;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel12;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel13;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel14;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel15;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel16;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem2;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField11;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField13;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField15;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField17;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField5;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField6;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField7;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField8;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField9;            
}
```

Comment: Засади эту строчку в try - catch

Comment: Если мой ответ Вам помог, отметьте его как принятый, пожалуйста, нажав на галочку возле него :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В конструкторе класса Вы сначала вызываете метод `getText()` для `jTextField2`, а только потом метод `initComponents()`, где этот самый `jTextField2` инициализируется.

```
public NewJFrame() {
    this.b = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText()); //вот тут Вы обращаетесь к jTextField2
    initComponents(); // но только тут он создается и обретает значение
}

private void initComponents() {
        ...
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField(); // в частности, аж тут
        ...
}
```

Конечно, возникает ошибка, так как в `jTextField2` пусто на момент обращения к нему. Попробуйте, например, поменять местами эти строки или инициализируйте `jTextField2` отдельно перед всем остальным в конструкторе.